# How to make a position: absolute ignore overflow-x and overflow-y hidden?

Tags: html, sass

I have a div with buttons, when you click on which, a block with a `position: absolute`,
But if I want there to be no overflow for the block, then the pop-up block does not appear.

Comment: You can’t. You’ll need to reparent the positioned element elsewhere in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this should fix it `position: fixed`